# Using numpy.tile to repeat 2D arrays

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, repeat, tile

I have 3 arrays:

```
e = np.array(range(3,100))
dRdE = np.load('arr_25.npy')
```

The npy file contains an array with random values but is of the same length as e. I then take the outer product of `dRdE` with another array.

```
s = np.array(range(1,100))
dRdE = np.outer(s, dRdE)
```

And so `dRdE` is now 2D.

I want e to repeat the number of times of each element in `dRdE`. I could use `dRdE` before when it was 1D and of the same length as e using numpy repeat. The code I had before was:

```
earray = np.repeat(e, dRdE)
```

But since dRdE is no longer 1D I thought I might be able to use `np.tile` but I'm not sure exactly how to.

The context might help, so I have an energy varying between `3keV` to `100keV` and I have an array containing the number of events (`dRdE`) for each energy between that range. But now I want to introduce a third variable that is just some factor of dRdE between 1 to 100. So for example if:

```
dRdE= [1,2,1,2..],[2,4,2,4..],[3,6,3,6]
```

I want:

```
earray=([3,4,4,5,6,6,...],[3,3,4,4,4,4,5,5,6,6,6,6,...],[3,3,3,4...])
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Do the sublists in `earray` differ in length?  If so, then you probably just have to apply `repeat` row by row.  `tile` is for patterns that apply across rows and/or columns - a regular tile pattern, not a mosaic.

Comment: Yeah they do unfortunately, so would tile work then if the sublists were of the same length?

Answer (score 0):

I asked about variable length sublists because that is a clear indicator that some sort of iteration is required.  There aren't many `numpy` operations that produce a list or tuple of differing length arrays.

Looking into `tile` a bit more (it's not something I use everyday), I don't think it helps at all.  Its `reps` are one value per *dimension*, not per *element*.

But lets explore `repeat`.

```
In [73]: vals=[[1,2,3,4],[11,12,13,14],[21,22,23,24]]
In [74]: reps=[[1,2,1,2],[2,3,2,4],[3,6,3,6]]
In [75]: valA=np.array(vals)
In [76]: repA=np.array(reps)
```

An iterative solution:

```
In [77]: [np.repeat(v,r) for v,r in zip(valA,repA)]
Out[77]: 
[array([1, 2, 2, 3, 4, 4]),
 array([11, 11, 12, 12, 12, 13, 13, 14, 14, 14, 14]),
 array([21, 21, 21, 22, 22, 22, 22, 22, 22, 23, 23, 23, 24, 24, 24, 24, 24,
       24])]
```

We could also apply `repeat` once

```
In [78]: np.repeat(valA.flat,repA.flat)
Out[78]: 
array([ 1,  2,  2,  3,  4,  4, 11, 11, 12, 12, 12, 13, 13, 14, 14, 14, 14,
       21, 21, 21, 22, 22, 22, 22, 22, 22, 23, 23, 23, 24, 24, 24, 24, 24,
       24])
```

Now if only we could split that array into 3 arrays, each 6,11,18 elements long.

```
In [79]: [len(np.repeat(v,r)) for v,r in zip(valA,repA)]
Out[79]: [6, 11, 18]

In [80]: np.split(np.repeat(valA.flat,repA.flat),[6,17])
Out[80]: 
[array([1, 2, 2, 3, 4, 4]),
 array([11, 11, 12, 12, 12, 13, 13, 14, 14, 14, 14]),
 array([21, 21, 21, 22, 22, 22, 22, 22, 22, 23, 23, 23, 24, 24, 24, 24, 24,
       24])]
```

I'm sure there's a faster way way of calculating [6,17] list.

But when I do a `timeit` I find that the list comprehension is faster (10x) than the split.  It's even faster that the single repeat.  Timings will vary with larger arrays, but getting around the list iteration does not look promising.

Comment: Is it possible to write it such that `vals=[[500,501,502,...,600]]` where vals is just a 1D array as opposed to having sublists and `reps=[[1],[2],[3],[4]....,[10]]` then using repeat to give out an array with sublists    `[[500,501,502,....],[500,500,501,501,502....],......]`